# shape file in HTML page

Tags: python, gis

Hellow i want to include shape file in the webpage.  please check below code .it is not working

```
import folium
import geopandas as gpd

# Read the shapefile
shapefile_path = 'c:/Users/HP/Desktop/qwer/congress/CONGRESS113_POLY.shp'
#shapefile_path = 'Path_to_shape.shp'  # Replace with the actual path to your shapefile
gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)

# Create a map centered around the shapefile
m = folium.Map(location=[gdf['geometry'].centroid.y.mean(), gdf['geometry'].centroid.x.mean()], zoom_start=10)

# Add base map tiles
folium.TileLayer('cartodbpositron').add_to(m)

# Add the shapefile to the map
folium.GeoJson(gdf).add_to(m)

# Save the map as an HTML file
m.save('c:/Users/HP/Desktop/map8.html')
```

Comment: Maybe the [doc](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/getting_started.html) can give you direction.